# Custom transformation with Glide

Tags: android, transformation, android-glide

I have custom transformation class like this:

```
public class MyTransformation extends BitmapTransformation {
    Context context;

    public MyTransformation(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
    }





    @Override
    protected Bitmap transform(BitmapPool pool, Bitmap toTransform,
                               int outWidth, int outHeight) {

        return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.viggi_rec);
    }

    @Override
    public String getId() {
        // Return some id that uniquely identifies your transformation.
        return "MyTransformation";
    }
}
```

And here is usage:

```
 try {
            Glide.with(context)
                    .load(topList.get(i).getPhoto().get(0).getSrc())
                    .asBitmap()
                    .transform(new MyTransformation(context))

                    .into(homeViewHolder.imageView);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.print("Caught the exe");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

My problem is, the image not load and just transform apply correct.
When I clear the transformation the image is loaded and everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  try {
                Glide.with(context)
                        .load(topList.get(i).getPhoto().get(0).getSrc())
                        .asBitmap()
                        .bitmapTransform(new MyTransformation(context))

                        .into(homeViewHolder.imageView);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.print("Caught the exe");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }to( imageView1 );
```